# Mex - pass 3 dimensional Array as output

Tags: c, arrays, matlab, mex

My problem is that I want to pass a 3 dimensional array as output to matlab and work with it in a seperate C void function.. But when I try my Matlab Crashes. I have almost just started working with mex functions and have created others that works with no problems, but they have only been outputting arrays and single values.

Here is my Code.:

First file is my entry file called pm_motion_entry.c .:

```
#include <mex.h>
#include <matrix.h>

/* The gateway function */
void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[],
                 int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[])
{
/* Variable declarations here */    
    double sigma;   
    double L;
    double radius;
    int N;
    int M;

    double *outMatrixOne;
    mwSignedIndex *outMatrixTwo;
    mxArray *Array;

/* Dimensions for cell array */
    mwSize dim[2] = {M,N};

/* checks for right type*/
    if(nrhs != 5) {
        mexErrMsgIdAndTxt("MyToolbox:arrayProduct:nrhs","Inputs: sigma, L, radius,  N, NumberOfParticles");
    }

    if(nlhs != 2) {
        mexErrMsgIdAndTxt("MyToolbox:arrayProduct:nrhs","Too Few output argumetns, Output is I and Particle");
    }
    sigma = mxGetScalar(prhs[0]);   
    L = mxGetScalar(prhs[1]);
    radius = mxGetScalar(prhs[2]);
    N = mxGetScalar(prhs[3]);
    M = mxGetScalar(prhs[4]);

    if( !mxIsDouble(prhs[0]) || !mxIsDouble(prhs[1]) || !mxIsDouble(prhs[2]) || !mxIsDouble(prhs[3]) || !mxIsDouble(prhs[4])) {
        mexErrMsgIdAndTxt("MyToolBox:arrayProduct:notScalar","Input 1,2 and 3 should be of type double, and 4 and 5 should be of type Integer.");
    }

/* create output matrix */
    plhs[0] = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(N,1,mxREAL);
    Array = mxCreateNumericArray(2,dim,mxDOUBLE_CLASS,mxREAL); /* Two cell arrays one for x positions and one for y positions*/

/* assign pointer to output*/
    outMatrixOne = mxGetPr(plhs[0]);
    outMatrixTwo = (mwSignedIndex*)mxGetData(Array);

/* run function */
    pBm_motion(sigma,L,radius,N,M,outMatrixOne,outMatrixTwo);
}
```

And my main function for calculations called pm_motion.c .:

```
#define _USE_MATH_DEFINES
#include <math.h>
#define UNIFORM ((rand()+0.5)/(RAND_MAX+1.0)) /* uniform inside [0,1] */
#include "mex.h"
/* Function for the calculation of the Intensity spectra of pure Brownian motion in FSC data */
void pBm_motion(double sigma, double L, double radius, int N, int M, double *In, double ***Particle)
{   
    /* Inputs/Outputs: D is the diffusion coefficient, tau is the size of timesteps, L is the length of on side of the system, radius is the radius of the focal volume, N is the number of time steps and M is the number of particles */
    /* Initialization of Parameters */
    int n = 1;
    int i;
    double pos_x,pos_y;

    /* The random walk and advancement in time */
    /* First place all particles randomly, this is t=0 */
    for(i = 0; i <= M; i++){
        Particle[i][0][0] = (-1.0)*UNIFORM + 0.5;
        Particle[i][0][1] = (-1.0)*UNIFORM + 0.5;
        In[0] += exp(-((Particle[i][0][0]*Particle[i][0][0])+(Particle[i][0][1]*Particle[i][0][1]))/(2.0*radius*radius));
    }

    /* Then we let time flow in the system */
    while(N >= n){
        for(i = 0; i <= M; i++){
            /* Using the Box-Muller Method to generate random normal distrubuted number to find the new position */
            pos_x = Particle[i][n][0] + sigma*sqrt(-2.0*log(UNIFORM))*sin(2.0*M_PI*UNIFORM);
            pos_y = Particle[i][n][1] + sigma*sqrt(-2.0*log(UNIFORM))*sin(2.0*M_PI*UNIFORM);

            /* Double Periodic violation */
            if(pos_x > (L/2.0) && pos_y > (L/2.0)){
                pos_x = -(L/2.0)+(pos_x - (L/2.0));
                pos_y = -(L/2.0)+(pos_y - (L/2.0));
            }
            if(pos_x < -(L/2.0) && pos_y > (L/2.0)){
                pos_y = -(L/2.0)+(pos_y - (L/2.0));
                pos_x = (L/2.0)+((L/2.0) + pos_x);
            }
            if(pos_x < (L/2.0) && pos_y < -(L/2.0)){
                pos_x = -(L/2.0)+(pos_x - (L/2.0));
                pos_y = (L/2.0)+((L/2.0) + pos_y);
            }
            if(pos_x < -(L/2.0) && pos_y < -(L/2.0)){
                pos_y = (L/2.0)+((L/2.0) + pos_y);
                pos_x = (L/2.0)+((L/2.0) + pos_x);
            }

            /* Periodic Boundary condition invoked, maybe.. */
            if(pos_x > (L/2.0)){
                pos_x = -(L/2.0)+(pos_x - (L/2.0));
            }
            if(pos_y > (L/2.0)){
                pos_y = -(L/2.0)+(pos_y - (L/2.0));
            }
            if(pos_x < -(L/2.0)){
                pos_x = (L/2.0)+((L/2.0) + pos_x);
            }
            if(pos_y < -(L/2.0)){
                pos_y = (L/2.0)+((L/2.0) + pos_y);
            }
            /* Update position. */
            Particle[i][n][0] = pos_x;
            Particle[i][n][1] = pos_y;
            /* Calculate Intensity */
            In[n] += exp(-((Particle[i][n][0]*Particle[i][n][0])+(Particle[i][n][1]*Particle[i][n][1]))/(2.0*radius*radius));   
        }       
        n++;    
    }
}
```

I have I feeling that it is the way i access the 3D Matrix in the Entry file, But I don't know enough about mex yet to be really sure about it.

Comment: What I do in my code is, work with a C++ array, and *after*, assign the output. Now your C++ fun is supposed to get a double** but instead you give to it some  mwSignedIndex thingie.

Comment: I'd suggest you try to do something like: https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/matlab/680/introduction-to-mex-api/14732/pass-a-3d-matrix-from-matlab-to-c#t=20161108165432036178